# Нужно вывести многомерный массив в шаблоне tpl smarty

Tags: php, массивы, smarty

Есть массив:

```
array (
  1044 => 
  array (
    'date' => 
    array (
      0 => '2016-06-18 14:52:25'
    )
  )
)
```

Подскажите как в шаблоне tpl вывести 'date' без `<section>`?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен)
Запустил цикл в цикле:

```
{foreach item=row from=$usersList}
   {foreach key=date item=time from=$row.date}
        {$date} отработано часов за день: {$time}
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```